# Is it possible to change contents dynamically which Alexa skill shows without any user actions?

Tags: firebase, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I want to create a Photo Frame Skill for Echo Show.
I want to change photos triggered by external server (such as Firebase and so on).
Is it possible to change it dynamically without any user actions?

I saw Notification API and Proactive Events API.
But, These show notifications to user. I don't want to show anythings to user.
I want just trigger controlled from external server to change contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on the type of skill (for example if it is based on Alexa Conversations or not). But you can try exploring something along this line:

1. Keep the token of last rendered APL document
2. Send an APL ExecuteCommand directive from your skill server (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-interface.html#executecommands-directive)
3. You can use one of the standard APL commands, depending upon your use case. One option is SetValue command (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#setvalue-command) to modify the background image.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a Photo Frame Skill for Echo Show

[Technically,](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-format) a skill can last for a maximum of 5min30sec without any user interaction. Only if you provide a prompt that last for 4min then a reprompt that last for 90sec. It could be a blank audio. But Alexa is not suited for custom skills that stays live for a long time without user interactions.